# ViewController's UILayoutAnchor messed up when added to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm playing around with UILayoutAnchor and it works perfectly with my ViewController. But when I add the ViewController to a NavigationController, I didn't get the result I'm expecting. Here's the code:

```
UIButton *topContainer = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[topContainer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:topContainer];
//Setup anchor
topContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[topContainer.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = true;
[topContainer.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = true;
[topContainer.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[topContainer.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = true;
```

the  result of the above code:

[image]

Now when I make the same ViewController as a root of NavigationController (via storyboard where I also hide intentionally) the same code gives the below result.

[image]

The first I've noticed is the background that went from gray to black. The interaction on the viewcontroller also is not working anymore. I've check the inspector of the navigationcontroller and its "user interaction enabled" is checked. And the topContainer(redbar) didn't extend to the edge of the screen.

I've tried using the viewcontrollers readableContentGuide but it extends all the way to the edge. See below code along with the result.

```
[topContainer.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = true;
[topContainer.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor].active = true;
```

[image]

I also tried showing the NavigationController and a clean build but it still gives the same result. Where did I messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Teddy bear programming really works. The problem is somewhere in my code there is this line.

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

I got the result I want by just commenting/removing it out. I'm leaving this here just in case someone encounter it.